# Image classification in video stream with contours with Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, svm

Please I need your help with this problem, I want to create a program to differentiate between the two forms(2 images), with a camera in real time, here are the methods. I found but I’m not sure they’re going to work because I want the detection to be feasible if the object is inclined by 90 degrees or 180 degrees by example, I have to use machine learning in this problem but I am open to any proposition, also I do not have many images in the database.

Here are the methods I found but I'm not sure they will work;

1 - Apply Canny filter to extract contours.

2 - Use a features extractors such SIFT, Fourier Descriptors, Haralick's Features, Hough Transform to extract more details which could be summarised in a short vector.

3-Then train SVM or ANN with this vector.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

The goal is to detect two cases : Open or Close

Also i dont know that contours are the best way to solve this problem because the background changes a lot

The original images are valves with different shape, here is an example :

[image: Image close]

[image: Image open]

Comment: whats the original image which is the object when open and close? can give image and label? GIVE propper example image so that others can give propper suggestion.  If background keep changing, you might have bigger issue in getting training sample. learning based method suffers from generalization is a common sense.

Comment: Thank you for your responds, The original images are valves with different shapes, I add two images

Comment: is handle always red? or is the background always white?   as far as the 2 sample given. You can just use object segmentation method like graph cut or anything. if the output fit T shape (done by e.g contour fit/ rect box ratio fit or anything), then it is close. else it is open.

Comment: Yes the handle is red, but the background changes a lot, I have the idea to use color for identification, and I must use machine learning in the project, my problem is that color is not a sufficient information, I need to detect the cases Open/close by detecting the T shape as you said, I don't know if the graph cut is going to work if the background changes, also do you have  any idea please how many images I have to use in the database to solve this problem with machine learning if I give HOG descriptor to a machine learning algorithm like SVM or ANN? and thank you.

Comment: for svm you need at least a couple hundred image sample,  CNN is usually more than a few thousand image sample.  since you only have open or close. use piror based graph cut may help by only find the maximum response of mean open and mean close

Comment: I have done some research about graph cut, but I don't know how to start, can you give me please a tutorial or an article to start with, I know how graph cut works, but I don't know how to use it in my case to detect the cases open and close in a video.

Comment: look at this paper and you will understand what I`m talking about. https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Segmentation-of-a-bird-and-a-cup-using-continuous-graph-cuts-and-the-corresponding-u-x_fig3_220931787.  This is only one of the method. there are a lot more other methods. So you have to go though those paper which cited graph cut and with keyword prior / learning etc .  You can also go for snake energy function for this. As i said there is no limit to your approach.